How to show a combinatoric of two sets?
I have two sets and a complex function,
A = {a,b}
B = {c,d}
f(a_i,b_i) = blah

what is the term and notation in latex for conveying a combinatorial production on the two sets that would result in a third set;
C = {f(a,c), f(a,d), f(b,c), f(b,d)}

Is it simply 'combinatorial production' and notation;
C = A \otimes B

Or would I lay it out with a \forall or \foreach, like I'm writing software?

Maybe C = A \otimes_f B?

I think you need to ask for the term and notation on [math.se]. Then, if you have trouble finding that notation, you can ask here, or look for it here: How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?

@Werner - when I ask a question like this that does not "forward the field of mathematics", it gets closed as "off topic".  They don't see a dumb person asking a dumb question as an opportunity to teach, but rather as a nuisance.

@CAB: Did you ask there and it got closed? I don't see that. You've been a member of that site for at least 7 years, so should know how to phrase something they could answer. Alternatively, post a question on their Meta in terms of phrasing to help you formulate something that could solicit a response.
